# how to use vlookup to populate a listbox on a userform after inputting a number in a combobox on the same userform using excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a userform in excel 2010. I want to input an employee number in ComboBox9 and when I press tab, I want another listbox to show the lastname of who has that employee number. Then I can continue with entering data in the other userform boxes...I am working with this so far but it wont work.

```
Private Sub TextBox531_Change()
   Dim LName As String
   LName = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox9.Value, Worksheets("Tables").Range("Officers"), 2, False)
   TextBox531.Value = LName
End Sub
```

It returns the error:

> Error says Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction
>   class

Comment: Error says Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

Answer (score 0):

When running your code:

```
Private Sub TextBox531_Change()
   Dim LName As String
   LName = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox9.Value, Worksheets("Tables").Range("Officers"), 2, False)
   TextBox531.Value = LName
End Sub
```

I get no errors.

one of the options to get the error: "Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction" as you got means that there was no lookup found. meaning, if I will put this lookup in excel I will get #NA.

To resolve this you can use `ifna` function or first check that the value from your combob ox (ComboBox9.value) is exist in the left most column of you officers range.

Comment: Is my syntax ok? And yes my first column is numbers and second is names in the range I called Officers from my Tables worksheet. Something with the Vlookup is the problem....Argggh. Is there is another way to write this?

Comment: Your syntax is good. When you get the error code and pointing your combo box value, does it show some value or empty? It it shows a value, is it found in officers?

Comment: yes it shows me the value and yes it is in my Officer range

Comment: What about case sensitive issues? A sapce perhaps? Format changes?

Comment: now I got it where it wont give me an error but it wont populate the last name in textbox 531. Let me see if we are on the same page. When I open my worksheet my userform opens. The first thing I do in Combobox9 is to put the employee number and upon tabbing or entering, I want textbox531 to, pop in the last name from my Tables worksheet in the same workbook in the range called Officers. Seems I cant get the name to populate now. error is gone but nothing shows up in textbox531.

Comment: Instead of the combobox try to enter a valid number that exist in officers

Comment: No, it will not show the name in the textbox531 with just the number. Thats why I am wondering if the syntax is wrong using 2010 excel.

Comment: msgbox(LName) gives nothing as well?

Comment: Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction. Same error.

Comment: I am so lost with this. Maybe a dumb question but, If I change the first ComboBox9 and then hit enter, the cursor tabs to my TextBox531. Where would I put the above code? Would it go in the Sub TextBox531 change?